# Using __get() on array class properties to auto-propogate with a class

Tags: php, magic-function

I have a activerecord model which has an array in it of say: "$sessions". What I would like to do is make this a 2d array so as to be indexed in the following way:

```
["0"=>Session(Object), "1"=>Session(Object)]
```

Now to add cream on top I would like to make it so the user could do:

```
user->sessions[1]->id = "ghgh"
```

And the `__get` would understand whether there is an object already in that position in the class variable ("$sessions") and add/edit the property to the class or it will make a new class in that position called "Session".

I am a bit confused how I could get PHP (if possible) to get a __get on an index of an array.

Comment: I think I may have found my answer just now lol. By settings the object to a class implementing the arrayaccess interface I cna actually scroll through the array as an array and assign a new class to indexes which are none existant and edit object which do exist: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939677/set-get-with-array-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php).

> Interface to provide accessing objects as arrays.

Comment: Yes I believe so :) I will follow that answer I postede as a comment thanks for the strengthing of my idea :)